# C++ Builder TImage Load From URL

Tags: android, c++, ios, c++builder, timage

Am having trouble figuring out how to load an image from a URL into a TImage control.

Broadly, this is what I need to do

```
   TMemoryStream *str = new TMemoryStream;
   http->Get("http://myurl.mydomain.com/myimage.jpg", str);
```

The problem seems to be that str has no space allocated to it. And I get an "Invalid IO handle error".

I cannot find out the size of the image before hand.

How should I do this, please?  I tried to allocate 10MB of space to TMemoryStream by creating a dummy file and loading that file into the TMemoryStream but that also throws an "Invalid IO Handler" error.

Using C++ Builder on RAD Studio XE7 to develop iOS and Android apps.

Thanks a lot

Iyer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the code you have shown.  `TMemoryStream` grows dynamically as data is written into it, and `TIdHTTP::Get()` will write whatever data the server actually sends.  The code syntax you have shown is fine.

If you are getting an "IOHandler value is not valid" error from `Get()`, it means an **HTTPS** url is being requested but a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component (such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`) is not assigned to the `TIdHTTP::IOHandler` property to handle SSL/TLS encryption.  Your code is requesting an **HTTP** url, so the server is likely sending a redirect response to tell `TIdHTTP` to request an **HTTPS** url instead (check the `TIdHTTP::OnRedirect` event to verify).  You need to have an SSL IOHandler assigned in order to handle HTTPS urls.